# Insert Multiple array value in same row php

Tags: php, mysql

How can I insert Multiple array value in mysql table at same time? 
I can handle single value Insertion.

Eg:

```
$product = json_decode($_POST['product']); // (1,2)
$sub_product = json_decode($_POST['sub_product']); // (3,4)
$plan = json_decode($_POST['plan']);// (5,6)
$months = json_decode($_POST['months']); // (7,8)
```

I want to insert value with same index in mysql

Something like:

```
+----+---------+-------------+------+--------+
| id | product | sub_product | plan | months |
+----+---------+-------------+------+--------+
| 1  | 1       | 3           | 5    | 7      |
+----+---------+-------------+------+--------+
| 2  | 2       | 4           | 6    | 8      |
+----+---------+-------------+------+--------+
```

I've tried Insertion for single column and it works perfectly.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($product); $i++) {
        $product = mysql_real_escape_string($product[$i]);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO i_product(product) VALUES('$product')");
    }
```

Comment: would this help? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: `INSERT INTO i_product(product, sub_product...) VALUES('$product', '$sub_product'....)"` ?

Comment: `$product, $sub_product` are array and not string

Comment: @NehilMistry Yes, I just figured that part now. I've updated my answer. Please test your application with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute multiple `INSERT` operations in the following format,

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (a,b,c)
VALUES
    (d,e,f),
    (g,h,i),
    (j,k,l);
```

Here's the reference:

- [`INSERT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Since you're getting the data as an array, your `INSERT` operation should be like this:

```
// your code    

mysql_query("INSERT INTO i_product(product, sub_product, plan, months) 
VALUES 
('" . mysql_real_escape_string($product[0]) . "', '" . 
      mysql_real_escape_string($sub_product[0]) . "', '" .
      mysql_real_escape_string($plan[0]) . "', '" . 
      mysql_real_escape_string($months[0]) . "'), 
('" . mysql_real_escape_string($product[1]) . "', '" . 
      mysql_real_escape_string($sub_product[1]) . "', '" . 
      mysql_real_escape_string($plan[1]) . "', '" . 
      mysql_real_escape_string($months[1]) . "')");
```

**Sidenote:** Please don't use `mysql_` database extensions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.